# BOSH doesn't recognize deleted VM

Tags: openstack, cf-bosh

I'm working with BOSH on Openstack. I called `bosh -n deploy` to have BOSH update an existing deployment. The update required some slave machines to be brought down. As far as I can tell on the Openstack Horizon Web GUI and through command line calls to the Openstack tenancy I'm working on the VMs that should have been brought down have been. However, BOSH seems to think all but one have been brought down.

Is there a way to go into my MicroBOSH VM to edit an entry somewhere that will fix this error?

I can't be positive that the error is completely due to BOSH because the Openstack cloud that I'm working on is going to be completely rebuilt soon and therefore there could be any number of things happening behind the scenes that I don't know about. As such I just want to be able to stop BOSH from complaining about a VM that it can't delete (because it's already gone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `bosh cck` should take care of it.